# How to specify a Parse SDK object field name through an annotation?

Tags: android

How can I specify a [Parse](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android) object's field name through an annotation? I tried to find the answer on their [docs](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#the-parseobject) but I had no success.

Reason why I want to do it: **Safeness**.
I don't want that a var/val rename actually change the "column name".

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do it through an annotation, but I've just realized how we can do it by assembling the Parse model.

The parameter `name` in `attribute()` and `safeAttribute()` allows you to specify a custom name for that field.

Example:

```
@ParseClassName(value = "Person")
class PersonParseModel : ParseObject() {

    var name: String by attribute(name = "person_name")

    var email: String by attribute(name = "email")

    var profileImageUrl: String? by safeAttribute(name = "profile_image")
}
```